# Rgd File Replace Single Quote with Null

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, rename

Rgd File Replace Single Quote with Null

I have a lot of file which is

e.g

```
My's File.bat
My's Data.txt
My's Video.mp4
```

I am running Ubuntu OS, I want to mass replace the Single Quote ' with Empty

so it become

```
Mys File.bat
Mys Data.txt
Mys Video.mp4
```

How do I achieve this.

**Thanks**!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tr`

```
echo "my's File.bat" | tr -d "\'"
```

`\'` should be used to escape the single quote character

Comment: I trying mass file rename

Comment: This is changing strings, not file names.

Comment: My intention is not to spoon-feed the answer. I just wanted to point him/her that `tr` can be used to remove the single quote.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to loop through the files and move them to a name without `'`:

```
for file in *
do
    new_name=${file//\'/}
    mv "$file" "$new_name"
done
```

See the replacement we do with pure bash:

```
$ file="My's Video.mp4"
$ echo ${file//\'/}
Mys Video.mp4
```

In case files are throughout different directories, you will need to use `find`. Let us know so we can improve the answer.